# Android Pass the context of the Activity implementing the interface class to call the interface class methods from Service

Tags: java, android

Suppose i have an interface class:

```
public interface interfaceClass{
    void message();
}
```

The interface is implemented by two Activities A and B:

```
public class A extends AppCompatActivity implements interfaceClass{

      @Override
      public void message() {
           // message: this is class A implementing interface
      }
}

public class B extends AppCompatActivity implements interfaceClass{

      @Override
      public void message() {
           // message: this is class B implementing interface
      }
}
```

Now I have service where i want to call the method of the interface class implemented by both activities A and B by creating the object of the interface class but i don`t know **how to initialize the interface class object in order to call the method implementation from class A or B**

```
public class serviceClass extends Service {

      interfaceClass object = (interfaceClass)context;
      object.message();

}
```

Any suggestions how to get the context of the activity A or B to initialize the object???

Comment: `new A()` if you need `A` instance, `new B()` otherwise. No need to cast them to `interfaceClass` as both `A` and `B` are subtypes of this type.

Comment: I don`t want to initialize it by explicitly calling new A() or new B(), any way we can initialize it using the context of the activity?

Comment: Well, the question was 'how to initialize the  interface class object'. When you get an instance of `A` or `B` in whatever way you choose, it is automatically an instance of `interfaceClass`. If your question is 'how to obtain an instance of A or B in my `serviceClass`', you probably need to ask that :)

Comment: yes i have updated the question, check it now. how to get the context of the activity A or B?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy it's never correct to use `new` in order to create an instance of an activity

Comment: Yep, I've overlooked that that was an activity, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can solve this by using a Bound Service: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Then you could set up your activity hierarchy like this:

```
public abstract class ServiceActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyInterface {

    protected MyService service;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
        MyBinder myBinder = (MyBinder) binder;
        service = myBinder.getService();
        ...
    }
}
```

And

```
public class A extends ServiceActivity {...}

public class B extends ServiceActivity {...}
```

Now, in your service, you might have a method like this:

```
public void useInterface(MyInterface i) {
    i.doSomething();
}
```

Which you could call from your activity like this:

```
service.useInterface(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question: No way to get activity object in service.

In service, you can't obtain the `Context` of an activity. You can only get `Context` of service and `ApplicationContext`.

If you want to communicate with your activity from service you can use `BroadcastReceiver`.

More info about Broadcast: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html